# c++ Releasing memory of array pointer

Tags: c++

I have a function as below

```
void ReadMyPacket(int Socket)
{
  char *inStartup = new char[2];
  int recvReturn = recv(Socket, inStartup, 2, 0);
  ...
  ...
  delete[] inStartup; 
}
```

How should I release the memory of inStartup? I cannot use std::string because I have to pass the array in the recv function.

Comment: What is wrong with the way you have it? And better yet, just use the stack so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You can use `shared_ptr<>` if you want. Smart pointers are good for you. As @Cyber mentioned, there is nothing wrong with it unless you are intending to do something more with it (and tell us what).

Comment: When I call this function for second time, it crashes even when I have only those 3 lines in the code and everything else is commented hence I thought it could be memory issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax down right, however your reasoning is, slightly, flawed:

> I cannot use `std::string` because I have to pass the array in the `recv` function.

While `string` might not be the right interface, `vector` definitely is. The primary reason for `vector` being a contiguous array is interoperability with C.

You can thus write:

```
void ReadMyPacket(int Socket)
{
  std::vector<char> inStartup(2);
  int recvReturn = recv(Socket, &inStartup.at(0), inStartup.size(), 0);
  //...
  //...

}
```

And this way you will avoid risks of forgetting to call `delete[]` yourself (for example, in case of exception).

*Note: in C++11 and higher you can use `inStartup.data()` instead of `&inStartup.at(0)`.*

Comment: You could just use the new `std::vector::data()` function instead of `&inStartup.at(0)`.

Comment: @sjdowling: Ah right, I keep forgetting about that one.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic allocation for a 2 character buffer is overkill - just use a local buffer on the stack:

```
void ReadMyPacket(int Socket)
{
  char inStartup[2];
  int recvReturn = recv(Socket, inStartup, 2, 0);
  ...
  ...
  // nothing to dispose of here
}
```

Comment: How will this work without a constant expression? eg if I have a variable instead of 2

Comment: In that case you might want to use dynamic allocation, but your example used a hard-coded constant (2) for the size.

Answer (score 1):

That should be enough for freeing the memory.

```
delete[] inStartup;
```

However, if you are going to contain it inside a function and its not very large you better use stack, it is faster and does not need freeing.

```
char inStartup[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is properly deleting the memory.

```
delete[] inStartup;
```

conjured up by

```
new []
```